# Bug in Eclipse Juno & Neon - cannot open Console view again

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno, eclipse-neon

When I minimize the Console view, it disappears, and I cannot show it again using the `Windows > Show View > Console` menu.

How do I make this view visible without reinstalling Eclipse?

Comment: Had similar in Neon

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had the same problem too. Impossible to restore the console after minimizing it in Juno, and it wasn't appearing in the toolbar.

In the "Window" menu there is a "Reset perspective" link. It will restore Eclipse perspective to the one you had after a fresh install.

If the console is still not showing up after this operation THEN click on "Window" > "Show view" > "Console".

Comment: You saved an headache

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem, only I was having it with other views in addition to the console.  I was resetting my perspective continually.  I found that uninstalling the Astyle plugin resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you minimize viewparts in Eclipse, then they don't become completely invisible. The icons of the minimized views are still shown on a toolbar, that may sit on any side of the big Eclipse window. That toolbar has a button labeled "Restore", which is what you want.

Comment: I found that this caused my individual editor windows to "disappear", and I had to "reset perspective" again.  Thanks for the tip, though, I had not noticed the "Restore" button on the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding an eclipse short cut for the console ? That way you just to use/press the key combination for getting the console.

http://www.google.co.in/search?q=add+keyboard+shortcut+in+eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Just go to Windows menu and click on Reset perspectives. It fixes the problem.